# No CPU/GPU temp

Tags: cpu, gpu, temperature, amd-ryzen

Since the upgrade to 22.04, my CPU/GPU temps are not available. When attempting to configure the widget, only disk drives appear. It would be nice to monitor the temperature again.

```
CPU:
AMD Ryzen 3 2200G with Radeon Vega Graphics

Memory:
30737MB (10697MB used)

OS:
Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS

Display Resolution:
1920x1080 pixels

OpenGL Renderer:
AMD Radeon Vega 8 Graphics (raven, LLVM 15.0.7, DRM 3.47, 5.19.0-43-generic)

X11 Vendor:
The X.Org Foundation
```

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu. Try [Freon](https://github.com/UshakovVasilii/gnome-shell-extension-freon/wiki). I missed so many good top bar indicator applets of Ubuntu 20.04 LTS

Comment: You refer to "the widget" in your question. To what are you referring? Also, do you have `lmsensors` installed and configured?

Comment: Widget is a reference to the Plasma desktop widgets. Yes, lmsensors is installed.